# Second toggel should be close when i click back to the first toggle

Tags: javascript, toggle

I have tow toggles. I want appear only one toggle at the time. When i click to second toggle then first toggle should be close.

Javascript

```
$('#bar').click(function () {
    $('#foo').slideToggle('slow');
});
$('#bar1').click(function () {
    $('#foo1').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

HTML

```
<button id="bar">bar</button>
<div id="foo"></div>
<button id="bar1">bar1</button>
<div id="foo1"></div>
```

CSS

```
#foo {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: green;
    display:none;
}
#foo1 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: green;
    display:none;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kashifkiduniya/5JgXM/5/)

Comment: Just one thing that what would be process if i have 5 toggles. Because you are hiding first toggle to second and second to first. Please elaborate this Math for 5 toggles.

Comment: I've added changes http://jsfiddle.net/5JgXM/8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `classes` instead of `id's`

```
$('.bar').click(function () {
    $('.foo').hide();            // hide previous elements
    $(this).next().show('slow'); // show next element in the DOM (it will be <div> with class 'foo')
});
```

[`Example`](http://jsfiddle.net/5JgXM/10/)

Answer (score 0):

I did what you want with classes,
the accordion style,

```js
$('#bar, #bar1').click(function () {
    var id = '#'+$(this).attr('data-for');
    
    if ($(id).hasClass('open')) {
        $(id).toggleClass('open');
    }
    else if ($('#foo').hasClass('open') || $('#foo1').hasClass('open')) {
        $('#foo').toggleClass('open');
        $('#foo1').toggleClass('open');
    }
    else {
        $(id).toggleClass('open');
    }
});
```

```css
#foo {
    width: 100px;
    height: 0;
    background-color: green;
    display:block;
    transition: all .5s;
}
#foo1 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 0;
    background-color: green;
    display:block;
    transition: all .5s;
}

#foo.open, #foo1.open {
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="bar" data-for="foo">bar</button>
<div id="foo"></div>
<button id="bar1" data-for="foo1">bar1</button>
<div id="foo1"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response i got what i need.

Answer (score 0):

hi i have two ways which you can achive it

in this case the first div is sliding up when second div is opening

```
$('#bar').click(function () {
 $("div").slideUp("slow");
 $('#foo').slideToggle('slow');    

});
$('#bar1').click(function () {
$("div").slideUp("slow");
$('#foo1').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

[case 1 in fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/5JgXM/16/)

in second case am hiding the first div when am opening the second div

```
$('#bar').click(function () {
$("div").hide();
$('#foo').slideToggle('slow');    

});
$('#bar1').click(function () {
 $("div").hide();
   $('#foo1').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

[case 2 in fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/5JgXM/17/)

i hope my answer helps you  :)

Comment: I already did with the above  Alexander's example...its same as you wrote. Thanks so much for your response but its done.
Stay Bless